Set an event on ToastButton from background task
From a UWP application I start this background task:
namespace Background.UWP
{
    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private WatchLoop _watchLoop;

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            ApplicationTriggerDetails details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ApplicationTriggerDetails;
            var arg = details.Arguments["MyArg"].ToString();

            // Start a loop that periodically does some checks 
            // and, if necessary, displays a toast with button "Show Details".
            _watchLoop = new WatchLoop(arg, new ToastNotification());
            _watchLoop.Start();    
        }    
    }
}

Class ToastNotification is defined as follows:
namespace Background.UWP
{
    internal class ToastNotification : IToastNotification
    { 
        public bool Show(string message)
        {
            var button = new ToastButton()
              .SetContent("Anzeigen")
              .AddArgument("action", "reply")
              .SetBackgroundActivation();

            var toast = new ToastContentBuilder();
            toast.AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
             .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
             .AddText(message)
             .AddButton(button);
            toast.Show();
            return false;
        }    
    }
}

Somewhere in my WhatchLoop code I call method Show();
Now I don't know where to register the click event on button. Here I found that I have to implement OnActivated in App.xaml.cs. However, because the toast is displayed by a background task, I don't have App.xaml.cs.
What should I do?
Edit: BackgroundTask runs in a separate Windows Runtime Component.

Can you put the Show() function to the UWP project? There is no way to get OnActivated in Windows Runtime Component. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/raising-events-in-windows-runtime-components

The background task runs in a separate process. Runtime arguments are marshaled from the UWP app to this process. Is thre any way to check if the toast is closed by clicking the Close Button or by the Toast Button?

See here for the reason I have to use a Windows Runtime Component.

" Is thre any way to check if the toast is closed by clicking the Close Button or by the Toast Button?" Have you checked this document?  This should be the only way currently.

I found a simple solution for my purpose:
Just add these lines:
Uri uri = new Uri("myapp://<application>");
button.SetProtocolActivation(uri);

The only thing I'll have to find out is how the <application> URL has to be formed. (See this question.)
